# stereo jack outputs?

Tags: keyboard

All of my keyboards and other stereo gear have 1/4" jack outputs: L/mono, and R. Is there a good reason why one of those couldn't be a 1/4" TRS instead, so using one cable (lead) in place of two? I'm sure switching sockets could be put in instead - might even be able to use only one socket for mono/stereo application?

Comment: The R **is** a switching socket. plug left only & you get mono, plug R too & it splits to stereo. I'm not sure how you would manufacture a socket that would smart-switch depending on whether it sensed a TRS or just TR.

Answer (score 4):

From a mixing perspective, you want to be able to control each channel separately. So once you take the keyboard live, you either want a single mono connection for one channel in the mixer, or you want two separate left and right connections for two adjacent channels in the mixer.

Most line level pro audio inputs are 1/4" mono TRS balanced, but will also work unbalanced. So having separate outs for left and right makes it easier to connect to the most common inputs. DIs are almost always one or two mono 1/4" input with one or two XLR outputs, so once again.

PAs are run in mono so often that taking a stereo TRS out, splitting it into separate left and right 1/4" mono connections, and then mixing them together both panned center is a lot more trouble than simply having one TS output that is either mono or one of a stereo pair of outputs.

Finally, it's nice in the pro audio world to know that any TRS cable is balanced mono and not stereo. If some devices had stereo TRS outputs or inputs it would get a lot more confusing.

Answer (score 2):

There very likely IS a 1/4" stereo TRS output, labelled 'Headphones'. It won't be a lot of use for anything else, because 1/4" stereo INPUTS are uncommon.

Consumer gear often uses TRS mini-jacks for stereo though, and mixers etc. are beginning to feature a mini-jack stereo input for direct connection of a phone, tablet etc.  This might catch on for music gear.  Though I suspect the larger 1/4" TRS jacks will stay reserved for mono, balanced connections.

Comment: I reckon stereo inputs *and* outputs are uncommon! Although I do use a k'bd amp with stereo inputs. One lead! And it's the same for XLRs. always two! And there, a dedicated 4 or 5 pin XLR could be fitted - no problems with wrong connections!